# How to recover Data after "mdadm zero-superblocks"

Tags: data-recovery, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I wanted to swap from CentOS to Openmediavault. I had a RAID1 with mdadm in place and wanted to split it again into two separate disks. The [Guide](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Software_RAID_mit_MDADM_verwalten#Array_l.C3.B6schen) ([Similar to ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RAID#Removing_devices_from_an_array)) told me to do the following:

```
umount -l /mnt/nas
mdadm --stop /dev/md0

mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd1
```

Then I installed OMV5 and now I can not mount it because the superblock is gone(which I thought would not be a problem).

I will provide more information if needed.
Thanks in advance :)

fdisk:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FB8D182E-6744-4C9F-8E08-B3038729CA6D

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 5860524976 5860522929  2.7T Linux RAID
```

blkid:

```
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="NAS" UUID="2f0e4622-29fa-41e5-8cd5-bc1d8d5e98e0" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="01294e69-ee07-49ea-9d04-46b379d9c4c4"
```

mount:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /test
mount: /test: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: the title off that section literally is "delete the array" – uff. So, first thing: don't write to things, so especially don't try to mount things!

Comment: yeah i thought deleting the array refers to deleting the md0 point and transforming them to single drives again... I hope I didn't mess up everything.
Also the ArchWiki states: Remove device permanently (for example, to use it individually from now on): Issue the two commands described above then: mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdxx

Comment: yes, use the *device* individually, not the *data* on the device.

Comment: now, you don't happen to have the original way you created that raid, i.e. the `mdadm` call that created it in the first place.

Comment: Because then, you could run that again, with `--assume-clean`. But make a backup beforehand!

Comment: i am not sure, but i might have used the guide which I referred to. So your tip would be to call: "mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md/md_test --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdd1 missing" because I tinkered with the /dev/sdc1 so that its probably destroyed ...

Comment: puh, good question. I don't think `--raid-devices=2` will work if you only specify one device

Comment: so what i read is that if you set the second drive as "missing" this should work

Answer (score 3):

Ok i dont know how, but after testing all variants I finally managed to mount it again.

So I just called

```
mdadm --create --assume-clean /dev/md/md_test --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdd1 missing
```

and I could mount it to \test. I don't know how, because before testing everything in this Thread this did not worked but it does know

Thank you very much Marcus Müller for your time and effort :)

Comment: You're more than welcome! Happy it works! Please don't forget to run a filesystem check :)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping your raid was working fine without degradations, you can try the following:

1. make one of your physical partitions *readable* to your user, `chmod o+r /dev/sdd1`
2. Use `testdisk` on that to find the start of your file system within
3. use `losetup -o` (read the manpage!) to set up a loop device on /dev/sdd1 with an offset such that the it aligns with your findings from 2.
4. try `fsck.ext4 -n /dev/loopN`  (replace ext4 with the filesystem you used)

if that works, you can just mount /dev/loopN with your data on it.

Comment: thanks i will try that

Comment: as comments are not formatted I posted an answer

Comment: don't do that. you can add links like to pastebin to your comments, no problem.

Comment: ok then -> 

ok i ran testdisk and it auto selected "none" as partition map, should I manually set to to "EFI GPT" as I know form my fdisk call that it is GPT?

If not I am confused on how to find the start of the filesystem when I ran analyse the following is shown: https://pastebin.com/KLXTg53Z

Comment: well it is right that it shows none, because there's no partition table within that partition! But there's a point where your data starts. And as described above, you don't do anything to the drive with testdisk than noting down where that is, to use as offset in losetup.

Comment: ok, where do I read the start of my data? Because I don't have a clue where to read it from

Comment: there's a column called "start"...

Comment: ok, as there are several numbers in the same column I tried everyone and got the same output every time: https://pastebin.com/0wsCksFt (16 was the last number used, but I tried: 0, 1, 16, 80, 63, 364801 and 364817) Also it should be ext4 as I remember to have used it and blkid shows also ext4. Am I missing anything?

Comment: ok as I found out: mke2fs -n /dev/sdd1 provides backup superblocks: https://pastebin.com/sPCaYQyN
Should I try: "e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdd1"?

Never mind :( "mount -o -sb=98304 /dev/sdd1 /test" gives also bad superblock

Comment: you don't need a superblock for your file system, but for your mdraid. that's something different.